# write matrix as product of a diagonal and symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices

I have this matrix $A$ which is a $n \times n$ matrix:
$$
        A=\begin{pmatrix}
        b & c  & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a\\
        a & b & c &\cdots & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & a & b & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots &\vdots &\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & b & c\\
        c & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a & b
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
now, what we want to do is prove that $A$ can be written as a diagonal matrix times a symmetric matrix, where the trick is said to be in looking at $A-A^T$ calculating this I come to an anti-symmetric matrix. Now I have:
$$A-A^T=DS-SD$$
Here $D$ is a diagonal and $S$ a symmetric matrix. If I now compute this I can sort of see that this is correct. I'm however looking to write it a bit more mathematically than that. How to prove this?

Edit:
To elaborate a bit more on the coëfficients of the matrix:
$$a=\frac{1}{(\Delta x)^2} \frac{2}{\mu_j-\mu_{j-1}}$$
$$b=-\frac{1}{(\Delta x)^2} (\frac{2}{\mu_j-\mu_{j-1}}+\frac{2}{\mu_j-\mu_{j+1}})$$
$$c=\frac{1}{(\Delta x)^2} \frac{2}{\mu_j-\mu_{j+1}}$$
so $b=-(a+c)$.
A positive $\mu_j$ exists for every value from 1 up to $n$.
Also $\mu_{n+1}=\mu_1$, this means that the other way around: $\mu_{1-1}=\mu_n$

Comment: Are you sure the problem formulation is correct? If $a=0$ but $c\ne0$, it's easy to see that no solution exists. Actually, if $c^n\ne a^n$, there is no solution.

Comment: Maybe not entirely indeed, as I set a specific case. I eleborated a bit more on the coëfficients in the original question. But in a specific case where $\mu_j$ is constant over every $j$, the only addition I should do is that $a$ and $c$ are strictly positive and $b=-(a+c)$ and thus stricly negative.